# Unable to connect to Sybase ASE 16.0 at server

Tags: linux, windows, client-server, sybase, sap-ase

I am trying to connect to Sybase ASE version 16.0 installed at linux server through a windows client. However, I am unable to do so.
Please help me with an sql editor that supports Sybase ASE 16.X and Windows OS.
Also kindly help me with the steps to connect to the DB in client server architecture.

I am new to Sybase and Databases so excuse me if I asked something too obvious.

Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of tools to connect to a Sybase database but I would recommend the opensource software DBeaver (https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) thats allows to connect to lots of different type of databases. It will guide you on how to download the right jTDS driver to connect to a SAP/Sybase ASE db.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have done what you suggested. However, I am still getting following error when I test connection: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: Is there any firewall (iptables, firewalld) on linux server or on the windows server? Are the connection info correct (hostname/port)? Can the windows server be "ping"-ed from the linux server?

Comment: I am able to ping windows machine from Linux server and vice-versa.

At linux server:
sudo ufw allow from <client-ip> to any port <port number>
At windows client:
1. telnet <server-ip>
            As it gave error: 'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
2. Control Panel >> Programs >> Turn Windows >> checked Telnet Client
3. again tried telnet <server-ip> <port-no.>
               it gave: Could not open connection to the host, on port 5000: Connect failed
Now I am even more clueless

Comment: Are you sure the actual instance is on port 5000? If in doubt ask your DBA to give you the host port via select * from master..syslisteners to confirm for sure

Comment: I agree with Rich Campbell. Ask DBA to run this query or check on linux server the Sybase ASE config file $SYBASE/interfaces to know the port in use by ASE. Also make sure that ASE is up  (using either netstat or showserver or the ASE log file).

Comment: @Vince I have confirmed it using the same technique. The port number is 5000. I lso confirmed that the firewall at client and server if off/inactive at the moment.I also tried connecting to Sybase using jConnect driver instead (was using jDTS earlier) but got the same result. Is there any permission that I need to provide at server end in order to client to access server? Are there some environment variables that I need to set at client?

Comment: @RichCampbell I confirmed and the port that we are using is 5000

Comment: @Vince the servers (data and backup server) are up and running

Comment: In all honestly I would download the Open Client package from the SAP site and try and connect with isql or interactive SQL tools which come with the package. You can easily test then with the dsedit utility (again which comes in the client) that the instance is listening on the port you set before you try and connect. I would expect  a 'login failed' type message usually not a 'connection refused' error which a Sybase instance wouldn't usually throw back to a client.

Comment: @Rich As per SAP site, SAP has discontinued PC-client for windows.Instead, we now have SDK (Software Devlopers Kit) for SAP ASE and then we have to pick the Windows platform. I will try to go this approach once.

Comment: Yeah the SDK is the same thing as the old Open Client - apologies I've been a DBA on Sybase for about 17 years so I use the old terminology sometimes :)

Comment: @RichCampbell..thank you for your inputs, I have configured SDK at my end now. However now when I try to connect to DB through isql using command : isql -Usa -S<server name> through command line, I get error: ct_connect(): directory service layer: internal directory control layer error: Requested server name not found. I have set all the environment variables and made sure that the server name is correct. I have updated sql.ini with the same server name I found in interfaces file. However, still getting the issue. Can you please help me with the setting I might be missing.

Comment: @RichCampbell I have also tried to ping the server object using dsedit, however, I am getting error: 10061. No connection could be made because the target machine have actively refused it.

Comment: You need to add the server with the allocated port to your SQL.ini file on your pc via the dsedit tool which will fix the 'server name not found' issue. If that's also failing to connect you definitely have a firewall or similar network routing issue - try also using the IP address rather than the hostname to ensure you don't have a DNS lookup issue in resolving the machine name.